# Laravel Livewire get current page ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In a view I include a livewire component like so:

```
<livewire:search-comments :post="$post">
```

I can pass in the post as shown above. But the problem is that this is only done on `mount()`:

```
public function mount($post)
{
    $this->post = $post;
}
```

In `render()`, I have:

```
$comments = $this->post->comments()
    ->where('comment', 'like', "%{$this->search}%")
    ->get()
```

The problem is that I need to access `$post` on every `render()` call, because the comments searched are tied to the post the user is currently on. I could pass the post ID in a hidden field but that doesn't feel like the right (and a safe..?) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are various way to achieve this. Like you can emit an event when user tries to load a new post. then use magic method $refresh to refresh the component.

```
  protected $listeners = [
        'newPostLoad' => '$refresh',
    ];
```

or,

you can pass post id while use try to load new post. like this:

```
// as per your snippets above I assume ur blade has post collection which holds id for each posts.


wire:click=loadNewPost(id)
```

then u can reset your $this->post inside loadNewPost function.

Hope this helps. let me know. I will elaborate again

Comment: I never realised that $this->post will always stay in sync, even after the first mount. So there's actually no need to implement this, but your answer would still work and might help others in another related scenario.

Comment: yes, everything is reactive in Livewire. 

If you have a little Vue JS knowledge, everything of livewire will be super easy to you.